# How to checkpoint DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking for a way to checkpoint DataFrames.  Checkpoint is currently an operation on RDD but I can't find how to do it with DataFrames.  persist and cache (which are synonyms for each other) are available for DataFrame but they do not "break the lineage" and are thus unsuitable for methods that could loop for hundreds (or thousands) of iterations.

As an example, suppose that I have a list of functions whose signature is DataFrame => DataFrame.  I want to have a way to compute the following even when myfunctions has hundreds or thousands of entries:

```
def foo(dataset: DataFrame, g: DataFrame => Unit) =
    myfunctions.foldLeft(dataset) {
        case (df, f) =>
            val nextDF = f(df)
            g(nextDF)
            nextDF
   }
```

Comment: What if instead of checkpointing the `RDD`, we saved the `DataFrame` to a `Parquet` file and then loaded it back up? Is there any reason to suspect that would be faster?

Comment: @DavidGriffin It's an interesting idea.I think it's worth a try, but I couldn't say in advance if it would bring performance improvements. It probably depends strongly on the data structure and the frequency of saving/reading operations.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Another option that may help you improve performance is using `rdd.localCheckpoint` instead of the standard checkpoint. As can be seen in the [RDD docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD),  _"This is useful for RDDs with long lineages that need to be truncated periodically (e.g. GraphX)."_

Answer (score 23):

**TL;DR:** For Spark versions up to 1.6, to actually get a "checkpointed DF", my suggested solution is based on another answer, but with one extra line:

```
df.rdd.checkpoint
df.rdd.count
val df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
// df2 is checkpointed
```

---

**Explanation**

*Updated after further research.*

As pointed out, checkpointing a DataFrame directly is not currently (Spark 1.6.1) possible, though there is an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11879) for it on Spark's Jira.

So, a possible workaround is the one suggested on another answer:

```
df.rdd.checkpoint // Assuming the checkpoint dir has already been set
df.count // An action to compute the checkpoint
```

However, with this approach, only the df.rdd object will be checkpointed. This can be verified by calling `toDebugString` to `df.rdd`:

```
 scala> df.rdd.toDebugString
 (32) MapPartitionsRDD[1] at rdd at <console>:38 []
  |   ReliableCheckpointRDD[2] at count at <console>:38 []
```

and then calling `toDebugString` after a quick transformation to `df` (please note that I created my DataFrame from a JDBC source), returns the following:

```
scala> df.withColumn("new_column", lit(0)).rdd.toDebugString
res4: String =
(32) MapPartitionsRDD[5] at rdd at <console>:38 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[4] at rdd at <console>:38 []
 |   JDBCRDD[3] at rdd at <console>:38 []
```

`df.explain` also shows a hint:

```
scala> df.explain
== Physical Plan ==
Scan JDBCRelation (...)
```

So, to actually achieve a "checkpointed" DataFrame, I can only think of creating a new one from the checkpointed RDD:

```
val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
// or
val newDF = df.rdd.map { 
  case Row(val1: Int, ..., valN: Int) => (val1, ..., valN)
}.toDF("col1", ..., "colN")
```

Then we can verify that the new DataFrame is "checkpointed":

1) `newDF.explain`:

```
scala> newDF.explain
== Physical Plan ==
Scan PhysicalRDD[col1#5, col2#6, col3#7]
```

2) `newDF.rdd.toDebugString`:

```
scala> newDF.rdd.toDebugString
res7: String =
(32) MapPartitionsRDD[10] at rdd at <console>:40 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[8] at createDataFrame at <console>:37 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[1] at rdd at <console>:38 []
 |   ReliableCheckpointRDD[2] at count at <console>:38 []
```

3) With transformation:

```
scala> newDF.withColumn("new_column", lit(0)).rdd.toDebugString
res9: String =
(32) MapPartitionsRDD[12] at rdd at <console>:40 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[11] at rdd at <console>:40 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[8] at createDataFrame at <console>:37 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[1] at rdd at <console>:38 []
 |   ReliableCheckpointRDD[2] at count at <console>:38 []
```

Also, I tried some more complex transformations and I was able to check, in practice, that the `newDF` object was checkpointed.

Therefore, the only way I found to reliably checkpoint a DataFrame was by checkpointing its associated RDD and creating a new DataFrame object from it.

I hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: I'll say this -- so far it seems to be helping my `GraphFrame.aggregateMessages` operations. But I can't prove it.

Comment: I think the `count` action is not necessary after checkpointing. `createDataFrame` seems to be sufficient (in Spark 2.0.1).

Comment: I implemented this in pyspark with spark 1.6.1 but it takes a lot of time. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: is there any action faster than count()? like first()?

Comment: @ChristophHösler - no it doesnt work without the count for me on spark 2.0.1 - Create dataframe is a transformation and hence shouldnt be enough.

Comment: DataFrames in Spark 2.1+ now have a checkpoint method, which is faster than this approach since the DataFrame does not have to be converted to/from RDDs.

Answer (score 10):

As of spark 2.1, dataframe has a checkpoint method (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) you can use directly, no need to go through RDD.

Answer (score 6):

> Extending to Assaf Mendelson answer,

As of today Spark version 2.2, [`DataSet#checkpoint()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/12ab7f7e89ec9e102859ab3b710815d3058a2e8d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L529) API is **Evolving and Experimental**

### Usage:

Before checkpoint CheckpointDir has to be mentioned using SparkContext

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("checkpoint/dir/location")

val ds: Dataset[Long] = spark.range(10).repartition('id % 2)

// do checkpoint now, it will preserve partition also
val cp: Dataset[Long] = ds.checkpoint()
```

### How is works internally?

So far the [implementation for DataSet checkpoint](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/12ab7f7e89ec9e102859ab3b710815d3058a2e8d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L544) is to convert the DataSet to RDD then checkpoint it.

```
// In DataSet.scala 

//API we used in example  
def checkpoint(): Dataset[T] = checkpoint(eager = true)

//Base implementation
def checkpoint(eager: Boolean): Dataset[T] = {
    val internalRdd = queryExecution.toRdd.map(_.copy())
    internalRdd.checkpoint()

    if (eager) {
      internalRdd.count() //To materialize DataSet immediately on checkpoint() call
    }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The original question is about Scala Spark, but I think it is useful to add the PySpark syntax as well, which is very similar. Note that unlike `cache`/`persist`, `checkpoint` does not operate in-place (this tripped me up initially):

```py
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/foo/bar")
df = df.checkpoint()
```

Answer (score 4):

I think right now you'll have to do

```
sc.setCheckpointDir("/DIR")
df.rdd.checkpoint
```

And then you will have to perform your action on the underlying `df.rdd`. Calling `df.ACTION` will not work currently, only `df.rdd.ACTION`

Comment: How can I tell if this actually did the right thing?

Comment: @DavidGriffin You are correct. I updated my answer to be more correct. I'll also see if some of the work on streaming has resulted in a better api for checkpointing natively

Comment: Do you have to then recreate the `DataFrame` or does it already affect the top-level `DataFrame`?

Comment: @DavidGriffin as I said in an edit to my response, in my tests I noticed that the `dataFrame.explain` command was still pointing to the original data, that's why I recommended recreating it from the checkpointed rdd. Please let us know how it's working out.

Comment: @DanieldePaula your answer is a duplicate of this one -- but I appreciate the added insight.

Comment: What if instead of checkpointing the `RDD`, we saved the `DataFrame` to a `Parquet` file and then loaded it back up? Is there any reason to suspect that would be faster?

Comment: Sure, you'd ultimately be recreating the checkpointing functionality yourself.