# How can I save partial results of dataframe transformation processes in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working in `apache-spark` to make multiple transformations on a single Dataframe with python.

I have coded some functions in order to make easier the different transformations. Imagine we have functions like:

```
clearAccents(df,columns)
#lines that remove accents from dataframe with spark functions or 
#udf
    return df
```

I use those functions to "overwrite" dataframe variable for saving the new dataframe transformed each time each function returns. I know this is not a good practice and now I am seeing the consequences.

I noticed that everytime I add a line like below, the running time is longer:

```
# Step transformation 1:
df = function1(df,column)
# Step transformation 2.
df = function2(df, column)
```

As I understand Spark is not saving the resulting dataframe but it saves all operations needed to get the dataframe in the current line. For example, when running the function `function1` Spark runs only this function, but when running `function2` Spark runs `function1` and then, `function2`. What if I really need to run each function only one?

I tried with a `df.cache()` and `df.persist()` but I din't get the desired results.

I want to save partial results in a manner that wouldn't be necessary to compute all instruction since beginning and only from last transformation function, without getting an stackoverflow error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424445/

Answer (score 1):

You probably aren't getting the desired results from `cache()` or `persist()` because they won't be evaluated until you invoke an action. You can try something like this:

```
# Step transformation 1:
df = function1(df,column).cache()

# Now invoke an action
df.count()

# Step transformation 2.
df = function2(df, column)
```

To see that the execution graph changes, the SQL tab in the Spark Job UI is a particularly helpful debugging tool.

I'd also recommend checking out the [ML Pipeline API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html) and seeing if it's worth implementing a custom `Transformer`. See [Create a custom Transformer in PySpark ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331848/create-a-custom-transformer-in-pyspark-ml).